# How to fetch data from Web Service in VBA-Word?

Tags: web-services, vba, ms-word

How to fetch data from Web Service in VBA-Word?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short piece of code that should help:

http://developerresources.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/vbvba-call-webservice/

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to add a reference to the Soap Client COM library and consume a web service, and so I would rather go for the below approach:
http://esamsalah.blogspot.com/2005/11/consume-web-service-using-vb6-long.html